# how to collect metrics or time taken by GIT commands to complete

Tags: git, time, metrics

I need a help in collecting some metrics like how much time a GIT command or a script took to run.

Am aware that appending  time before the command would give the time taken to complete the GIT command,

But is there a better way or a tool for monitoring or collecting the metrics so that the tool calculates the time for each GIT command run by several develoeprs and records in a log?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use the bash `time` command?

http://ss64.com/bash/time.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can use:
CMD> powershell -Command "Measure-Command {echo foobar}"

It gives execution time as shown below:

```
D:\gh>powershell -Command "Measure-Command {echo foobar}"
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 31
Ticks             : 318183
TotalDays         : 3.68267361111111E-07
TotalHours        : 8.83841666666667E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.000530305
TotalSeconds      : 0.0318183
TotalMilliseconds : 31.8183
```